# Reactive Object is not updating on template Vue3 Composition API

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I'm struggling with this for a few days, maybe you could help me. I'm trying to fetch data from firebase (saved in `state.state.memory` and display it on my template. My variable **saved** updates on console, but template doesn't shows anything. I tried everything but I can't get anything on the template, could you explain?

Thanks!!

#### template

```html
<template>
  <div class="memory" id="memory">
    Memory
    <div class="elementos-memoria" v-for="item in saved" :key="item">
      {{ item.primero + item.operador + item.segundo + ' = ' + item.resultado }}
    </div>
    <div class="elementos-memoria" v-for="cuenta in cuentas" :key="cuenta">
      {{ cuenta }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

#### script

```js
import M from "materialize-css";
import { inject, reactive, watch } from "vue";

export default {
  props: {
    cuentas: Array,
  },
  setup() {
    const state = inject("store");
    let saved = reactive({});
    watch(
      () => state.state.memory,
      () => {
        saved = state.state.memory;
        console.log(saved);
      }
    );

    setInterval(() => console.log(saved), 1000);

    return {
      saved,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    M.AutoInit();
  },
};
```

#### Auth.js File

```
const state = reactive({
    user: {},
    memory: {},
})

const login = (email, password) => {
    let memory = []
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((data) => {
        state.user = data.user
        db.collection('users').doc(state.user.uid).collection('operaciones').get().then((queryResult) => {
            queryResult.forEach(doc => {
                memory.push(doc.data())
            })
            state.memory = memory
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    })
}

const signIn = (email, password) => {
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {
        state.user = cred.user;
    })
}


const logout = () => {
    auth.signOut().then(() => {
        state.user = null;
        state.memory = null;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you're replacing the reactive `state` value instead of mutating it

`saved = state.state.memory;` will replace it.

not sure what's in the `state.state.memory` object (assuming it is an object), but you can use `Object.assign` to dynamically update:

```js
if (state.state.memory) {
  Object.assign(saved, state.state.memory)
}
```

Comment: and why replacing it doesn't work? `saved` object should be identical to `state.state.memory`. I updated the code with `state.state.memory` information, thanks.
I resolved it defining `saved` as array instead of an object but I would like to know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: because the object created during `reactive({});` is not a regulat object but a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) , so when you re-assign it, the reactivity gets lost

Comment: You could even try using a `ref`, which you can re-assign that one by using `.value` however that won't watch for mutations within the object.